# Backbone reset a collection on fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

This is my problem:

- I have a container view that holds a collection.
- On page load I get some models, populate this collection with them, then render the models
- I fire and event
- When this event fires, I want to make a call to my api (which returns models based on input parameters)
- I then want to remove all existing models from the collection, repopulate with my new models, and then render the models

This is how I set up my model/collection/view

```
var someModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var someCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: someModel,
    url: "api/someapi"
});

var someView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #refresh": "refreshCollection"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        // render stuff
    },

    refreshCollection: function (e) {
        this.collection.fetch({data: {someParam: someValue});
        this.render();
    }

});

var app = function (models) {
    this.start = function () {
        this.models = new someCollection();
        this.view = new someView({collection: this.models});
        this.view.reset(models);
    };
};
```

My point of interest is here:

```
    refreshCollection: function (e) {
        this.collection.fetch({data: {someParam: someValue});
        this.render();
    }
```

I pass in some paramaters, and my api returns a json array of models.  I want to get rid of all existing models in the collection, and put all of my returned models into the collection, then update the view (with render())

I understand this is possible with collection.set, or collection.reset.  Both of these take in an array of models.  I don't have an array of models to pass in.

I tried:

```
this.collection.fetch({
    data: {someParam: someValue},
    success: function (response) {
        doSomethingWith(response.models)
    }
});
```

But I don't know what to do with the models when I get them.

Any pushed in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) *reset*.

So you just need to include `reset: true` in the options and `fetch` will call [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) to replace the collection's contents with the fetched models:

```
this.collection.fetch({
    data: { ... },
    reset: true
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I did console.log(this.collection.models) before and after the fetch (with reset: true).  The collection didn't change.  Do you have any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: What does `console.log(this.collection.toJSON())` say before and after the `fetch` call? Are you sure you've waited until the server has responded to the `fetch` AJAX call?

Comment: Ahhh.  I'm new to javascript and the asynchronous way of thinking.  That's what it was.

Comment: Cool, you'll get used to the async stuff soon enough. Careful with `console.log` too, it puts a live reference into the console rather than a snapshot of something's current state, hence the `toJSON` calls.